# Why did Apache IoTDB encapsulated by sessionpool reported thrift and connection reset error?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

What is the most likely cause of this error in Apache IoTDB (encapsulated by `sessionpool`)? I did not find any relevant questions for this error message, and I also cannot understand the error message by reading. The error information is `ERROR o.a.t.s.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:258 - Thrift Error occurred during processing of message. org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`. Is this because the maximum number of connections is not enough? Anyone know what may be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you called `sessionpool` to encapsulate Apache IoTDB, you still need to close your query tasks manually when IoTDB is innormally shut down, which should be the reason for the error you got. You can execute `sessionDataSetWrapper.close()` in your system, and the error should not be reported.